# Limit on the number of levels in bendable score

Tags: optaplanner

Just want to check if there is a limit on the number of levels in BendableScore. We have a POC where we have 2 hard constraints and 13 levels of soft constraints in BendableScore to give us a more fine-grained control over the scoring. My questions are:

1. Is there any limit to the number of levels of BendableScore?
2. If not, are there any issues(performance, correctness or otherwise), if we have these many level?

The number of levels may increase in the future to about 20, if we go with this POC approach. Is this advisable and/or recommended? I only saw this question asked on google: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/optaplanner-dev/Lw2GZCC2-Oc , which seems to suggest that the limit is 15. This was answered about 2 years back, so want to check if this is still valid.

thank you for your help.

best,

Alice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Limit on numer of levels is MAX_INT, so 2 billion.
2. The performance impact is neglectable, although I haven't tried 15+ levels, I expect it to be fine up to a 1000 or so.

**Are you sure you really need that many score levels? Aren't you confusing score weights with score levels?** See docs chapter 5. Usually there are only 2 or 3 levels, even when they are 20+ constraint types. Very rarely, I see a valid use case with 7 levels. But I often see use cases with 15 levels that should be using score weights instead - if they ask the trillion question to their users: Is breaking 1 trillion times constraint A still outweighted by breaking constraint B once? If yes, score levels are fine, but if not use score weighting.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will go back and see if these many levels are indeed needed.